# chart.js label color change based on value

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a horizontal chart of chart.js that looks like this.[my bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2QRz.png)

I am looking for a way to change the labels on the left "Boozman John, Eldridge Conner, etc." based on the values in a list that I get from an  ajax call.

I have tried something like

```
labels {
    fontColor: labelcolors
},
```

with a for loop to get colors in the list "labelcolors" but didn't work.

And here is my code

```
`var ctx = document.getElementById("GeneralChart");
var GeneralChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "horizontalBar",
    data: {
  labels: gen_candidate,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Committee expenditure",
      backgroundColor: "orange",
      borderColor: "yellow",
      borderWidth: 1,
      xAxisID: "expenditure",
      data: gen_expenditure
    },
    {
      label: "General votes",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      borderColor: "green",
      borderWidth: 1,
      xAxisID: "votes",
      data: general_votes
    },
  ]
},
    options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
        position: "top"
    },
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Money and Votes for General Election "+ state
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
                    position:"left",
                    id: "y-axis",
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: false,
                    }
                }],
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',  //type: 'linear', is needed for horizontal vote
            position: "top",
            id: "expenditure",
        }, {
            type: 'linear',
            position: "bottom",
            id: "votes",
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }   
    }
});`
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ticks: { 
    fontColor: "#377216", 
    beginAtZero: true 
    }
```